# single page application in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

i am new to MVC.....

i have some problem with single page application....

By using ...i want to make this kind of webpage...
  http://www.irealities.com/#team

1. Description of what i have tried...
   ====================================================================================

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>

             @**************SCRIPT CODE TO MAKE APPLICATION ONE SCROLL *************@

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".contactLink").click(function () {
            if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")) {
                $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
            }
            else {
                $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
            }
        });
    });
    function closeForm() {
        $("#messageSent").show("slow");
        setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        function filterPath(string) {
            return string
              .replace(/^\//, '')
              .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '')
              .replace(/\/$/, '');
        }
        $('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
            if (filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
            && location.hostname == this.hostname
            && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
                var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
                if ($target) {
                    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                    $(this).click(function () {
                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, 1000);
                        var d = document.createElement("div");
                        //d.style.height = "101%";
                        d.style.overflow = "hidden";
                        document.body.appendChild(d);
                        window.scrollTo(0, scrollToM);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
                        }, 10);
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <body>
      <section id="main">
         @RenderBody()
     </section>


 <div id="header">
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td><img src="Midasnext.png" alt="Midasnext LOGO" width="400" height="110">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td><div id="nav">        
        <a href="#HOME" class="Circle">HOME</a>
        <a href="#ABOUT" class="Circle">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#SERVICES" class="Circle">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#CLIENTS" class="Circle">CLIENTS</a>
        <a href="#CONTACT" class="Circle">CONTACT</a></div>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>


<div id="page-wrap">

    <div id="page1">

        <a name="HOME"></a>
        <div class="page-padding"></div>
        @*@RenderPage("~/Views/Clients/Index.cshtml")*@
         @*<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Clients/Index.cshtml"); %>*@
        <p>This is what you see on the HOME page.</p>
    </div> <!--END page1-->

    <div id="page2">
        <a name="ABOUT"></a>
        <div class="page-padding"></div>
        <p>This is what you would see on the ABOUT page.</p>
    </div> <!--END page2-->

    <div id="page3">
        <a name="SERVICES"></a> 
        <div class="page-padding"></div>
        @*@RenderPage("~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml")*@
        <p>This is what you see on the SERVICES page.</p>
    </div> <!--END page3-->

    <div id="page4">
        <a name="CLIENTS"></a>
        <div class="page-padding"></div>
        <p>This is what you would see on the CLIENTS page.</p>
    </div> <!--END page2-->

    <div id="page5">
        <a name="CONTACT"></a> 
        <div class="page-padding"></div>
         @*@RenderPage("~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml")*@
        <p>This is what you see on the Contact page.</p>
    </div> <!--END page3-->


</div> <!--END page-wrap-->
    </body>

</html>
```

=========================================================================================

## 2. Errors :-

suppose i clicked on clients menu items then then it shows content of client on client page as well as on end of page.

i am very confused , what to do and how to do ???
please frnd suggest me any solutions in MVC only......

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is not working for your.  Please post, (1) description of what you have tried, (2) description of what is going wrong with you have tried.   Also, please try to make questions as specific as possible.  This is a very large and vague question as it stands, and unlikely to get helpful answers.

Comment: thanx DWright for rply....i have modified the question....read it and please rply....thanx in advance.

Comment: Ok, the question is getting better! Thanks.  One more clarification:  could you post a screen shot of when it shows "content of client on client page and well as on end of page."

Comment: @MR.DWright....I have another Question for you -please help me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752185/asp-net-mvc-ajax-how-to-access-data-by-using-ajax